# JavaScript function not being called after Partial View refresh

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view on my table with an edit modal popup and I call a JavaScript function to populate the fields on popup:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editItemModalDialog" onclick="populateEditForm(42);">Edit</a>
```

Now all these values get loaded perfectly when the page is loaded but when I save the item and then re-render the partial view using jquery load method:

```
$('#tableContainer').load('@(Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController", null, Request.Url.Scheme))');
```

This way, the partial view gets updated but when I click the edit button now, the onclick button event doesn't calls the populateEditFrom function, what am I missing here?

Comment: As I recall, javascript needs to be within, or included from, the non-partial view which calls the partial view.

Comment: after saving....when you click the edit button...what  is shows in  developer console ????????????

Comment: if my code helped you kindly mark it as the answer, 
than you very much

Answer (score 1):

THIS CODE MIGHT HELP:
Ita will work 100% if your case is to fire an function 
After loading a view the "might" word is just because i have put it in a document.rady you can put in any event and give you what you want.

```
$(function(){
                    $.ajax(
                {url: "@(Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController", null, Request.Url.Scheme))",
                 success: function(result)
                {
                $("#tableContainer").html(result);
                **//<<FIRE YOUR FUNCTION HERE>>**
                }
                });
```

you can change the document ready to button click or anyevent u need

Comment: an explanation of " why your code may work"  would be beneficial and save you from downvotes